# PubNub subscribe is not Showing new messages

Tags: publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am using pubnub in my web application to show the notification.

```
    var newmsgCount = 0;
    Pubnub.init({
          subscribe_key: 'sub-key',
          publish_key: 'pub-key',
          ssl: true,
          uuid: 'ENV'+"_"+userIdNotificationId
        });
          Pubnub.subscribe({
            channel: 'ENV'+"_"+userIdNotificationId,
            callback: function (newMsg) {
              newmsgCount = newmsgCount + 1;

            }
          });
  Pubnub.history({
    channel:  'ENV'+"_"+userIdNotificationId,
    include_token: true,
    callback: function (messages) {
      var messagelist = messages[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < messagelist.length; i++) {
        newmsgCount = newmsgCount + 1;
      }
    }
  });
```

This is subscribe method i am using in my front end code.When i continuously push 3 or 4 messages to the subscribed channel it's only showing only one message in subscribe method.

Once i refresh the page i am reading the message count from pubnub history but there i am getting actual message count. But its not showing actual count in pubnub subscribe.

Any one please suggest whats the wrong in my implementation.

I update all code in above section in page refresh i will get the count from pubnub history function but in the pubnub subscribe is using to get the live count, once the user get new notification that count is read from pubnub subscribe. This count is not getting correct. Once the page is refreshed i am getting the actual count from pubnub history from same channel. I don't know why it's happening. Any other pubnub function available to get the live notification count for the user without page refresh. Please suggest

Comment: Please provide full code (with keys redacted), please.

Comment: update code with keys. Can you please check.

Comment: I was hoping to see ALL of your code so I have some context as to how this gets loaded and such. Can you provide a reproducible sample script if not your full code?

Comment: I updated all of my code in above section> Can you please check whats the wrong in my method.

Comment: What is the value of `userIdNotificationId`? What is your sub-key? Can you submit this to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com)?

Comment: "userIdNotificationId" value is like int numbers.

Comment: I would imagine, but I was hoping for an actual value you have used along with your sub-key so I can investigate.